# How to execute multiple Oracle queries in parallel

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have simple 25 oracle queries, each take almost 2-3hr to run.
If I am using Toad for it. 
Total time = 25x2hr = 50hrs

One option is: If I open 25 toad pages and paste each query in it I can execute them individually but I don't want to do that.

Is there any way that I can execute them by keeping them in one page but execute them parallel?

Comment: Maybe optimizing your query would be more successful. Have you considered what the load would be on your database to run 25 large queries all at once?

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL*Plus client instead of TOAD, submit each query in a separate file so they can all run in parallel. The output can be spooled into a separate file from each query.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to start Toad 25 times, Toad has option to open a new connection for each tab. So you will have to start each query in its own tab